# search in a table and count

Tags: javascript, html

This is a part of a code from my webpage,I have created a table 5x5 and I pass images to that table.I want,if that can happen to use a search function that every time someone selects one photo to show a message how many times exists this photo on the same table and it will mark the revisions of it.(border="5"). The function I have problem with is this.

```
function search(e){
//on that function 
//randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
//document.getElementById("anumber").innerHTML = "click on images: " + randomNumber;
//I am not sure if Is this the way to do it.
}





<body onload="loadImages()">


<table border="1" style="width: 100%" id="myT" onclick="search(event)">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k1.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k1.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to move `onclick="search()"` from table to every `img` ,that's because you have to work with image, which was clicked, not with whole table. You have to compare somehow clicked image with other images, right?

So I've searched for all `img` tags and then with `for loop` I have added them click event listener with search function.

Now when you click on image, you can catch that images src. That's will be the key for comparing with other images, since it's only unique value for every image.

Now when we have clicked image's src, we can compare it to other images. When they're equal we can add border to that image.

Everything's explained in code snippet below :)

```js
//Find all images
let allImages = document.querySelectorAll('img');

//Paragraph where we will display how many times we have same image
let result = document.getElementById('count');

//Add event listener to every image
for(let i=0;i<allImages.length;i++){
    allImages[i].addEventListener('click',search);
}

//Search function
function search(e){
    //Get clicked img src
    let clickedImgSrc = e.target.src;
    
    //Get rid of things we don't need. We will use only directory/imagename.jpg for comparing
    let clickedImgDirectory =clickedImgSrc.indexOf('my_files/');
    let clickedImgName = clickedImgSrc.substr(clickedImgDirectory);
    
    //Initialize counter
    let count = 0;
    
    //Loop thru all images, get src of looped image, get rid of things we don't need
    for(let i=0;i<allImages.length;i++){
        let imgSrc = allImages[i].src;
        let imgDirectory = imgSrc.indexOf('my_files/');
        let imgName = imgSrc.substr(imgDirectory);
        
        //Compare looped img with clicked img, if they're equal increase count by 1 and add border to that image.
        if(imgName === clickedImgName){
            count++;

            allImages[i].style.border = '5px solid red';
        }else{
            allImages[i].style.border = 'none';
        }
    }
    
    //Write count value to paragraph
    return result.innerText = 'This photo exists '+count+' times.';
}
```

```html
<p id="count"></p>

    <table style="width: 100%" id="myT">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k1.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k4.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k1.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k2.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k3.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
                <td><img src="./my_files/k5.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```